# Specific mask string finder - notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

in notepadd++ i need to find and mark all lines which contains string mask like first two characters of letters and last four numbers.

Example:

gj4290

wb1763

jp2860

...

What regex will complete that?

Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question and the points you gave in your answer, you could use `(?<=:)[a-z]{2}\d{4}$` if the stuff you want is always at the end of a line (as shown in your samples) or `(?<=:)[a-z]{2}\d{4}\b` if there can be multiple such constructs in a single line. In either case, don't tick *Match case*.

This makes use of:

- `(?<=:)` a positive lookahead to check for the presence of the colon, but not actually match it
- `$` an anchor for the end of a line
- `\b` word boundaries, between word characters and non-word-characters or start/end of line.

Comment: Thank you! You helped me so much!

Comment: I found another problem. How to find following strings: ULNNNN (uppercase, lowercase, 4 numbers). I tried this regex: (?<=:)[A-Z]{1}\[a-z]{1}\d{4}$ but it's not working. Can you please help me?

Comment: IIRC, there had to be a colon in the front of your string, is this still the case?

Comment: Yes it's still the case.

Comment: sorry it really works...my bad. I made a mistake in notepad++
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regexp:

```
^\w{2}\d{4}$
```